# JLabel: issue with accented letters

Tags: java, string, swing, character-encoding, jlabel

I read some string data from a JSON web service.

When I put the result string (with accented letters) into a `JLabel` I see the following result:
[image]

but the string should contain: *Lèttèrè àccèntàtè - àà èè ìì ò*

I use this code for declare the `JLabel`:

```
JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel(myString);
```

If I try to put this string into a .txt file a read the correct string (*Lèttèrè àccèntàtè - àà èè ìì ò*).

Is it an issue related to the charset that I use?

Comment: What is the code you use to put the text into the `JLabel`?

Comment: standard issue with charset and together/or with font

Comment: @durron597 I use this code: JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel(myString);

Comment: Are you setting the Font at all for the JLabel?

Comment: descriptionLabel.setFont(new Font(FONT_NAME, Font.BOLD, 12)); 
with FONT_NAME = "Arial"

Comment: How are you reading the data from the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, check if it works for you too and we can continue from there.

```
public class AccentedLabel extends JFrame {

    public AccentedLabel() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("áéêè");
        add(label);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new AccentedLabel();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Now try to replace all accented characters in your string with the following unicode strings and set them in the label.

```
á   \u00e0  Á   \u00c0
à   \u00e1  À   \u00c1
â   \u00e2  Â   \u00c2
é   \u00e9  É   \u00c9
è   \u00e8  È   \u00c8
ê   \u00ea  Ê   \u00ca
î   \u00ee  Î   \u00ce
ç   \u00e7  Ç   \u00c7
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I declare an accented String "hard coded" I don't have any issue. I store the string (returned from the web service) in my own object.

Comment: @MaTTP See my edit, tell me if it works and we will continue from there.

Comment: If I declare the JLabel like this: descriptionLabel = new JLabel("\u00e8"); it works

Comment: @MaTTP I want you to replace the characters in your string during runtime, such as with `String.replace` for example.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't the best approach

Comment: @MaTTP No, but it helps to isolate the problem. It seems to be in the way you are reading the string. What charset are you using to read?